# The difference between sess.run(c) and c.eval() in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When printing out the value of the node "`c`" in the following example, to me, it seems that there's no difference between `print sess.run(c)` and  `print c.eval()`. Can I assume that `sess.run(c)` and `c.eval()` are equivalent? Or are there any differences?

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(2.0, name="a")
b = tf.Variable(3.0, name="b")
c = tf.add(a, b, name="add")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print c.eval()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In TensorFlow, what is the difference between Session.run() and Tensor.eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610685/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-session-run-and-tensor-eval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `c.eval()` on a tensor, [you are basically calling `tf.get_default_session().run(c)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor). It is a convenient shortcut.

However, `Session.run()` is much more general.

1. It allows you to query several outputs at once: `sess.run([a, b, ...])`. When those outputs are related and depend on a state that may change, it is important to get them simultaneously to have a consistent result. People are regularly surprised by this [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43870531/1735003), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44129480/1735003).
2. `Session.run()` can take a few parameters that `Tensor.eval()` does not have, such as `RunOptions`, that can be useful for debugging or profiling.

   - Note however that `eval()` *can* take a `feed_dict`.
3. `eval()` is a property of `Tensor`s. But `Operation`s such as `global_variables_initializer()` on the other hand do not have an `eval()` but a `run()` (another convenient shortcut). `Session.run()` can run both.

Comment: And most importantly `sess.run` can handle a list compared to `.eval()` which causes [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177766/official-zeroout-gradient-example-error-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-at/50177935#50177935)